# Why is the majority bonus systems so rarely used across the world?

Tags: voting-systems

According to Wikipedia the [majority bonus system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_bonus_system) is used only by a few countries:

- Armenia
- San Marino
- Italy
- Argentina (Chamber of Deputies of the Province of Santa Fe and the Province of Entre Ríos only)
- Greece (abolished from 2016)

The main benefit is that provides government stability and if the bonus is small enough it should not automatically grant the winning party a comfortable majority.

**Question:** Why is the majority bonus systems so rarely used across the world?

Comment: so it's like even *more* winner-takes-all than winner-takes-all?

Comment: @endolith - if some cases yes, in others not exactly (e.g. the winning party gets some 30% seats)

Comment: What makes you think it's rarely used? That list doesn't try to be exhaustive. For example, in France, it's used for regional and municipal assemblies.

Comment: @Alexei Sounds like a horrible idea :/

Comment: It's used in the UK as well, as they use a first past the post system in each electoral district.

Comment: Being invented by Benito Mussolini is some impressively terrible political pedigree.

Comment: Governmental stability is not a benefit of a political system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple - because it is not fair.

The bonus system is only used as a compromised system in the countries where there are no stable, traditional political parties and politics is run by charismatic, mostly populist leaders (like in Italy or Greece).  In this case, it is almost impossible to make a coalition of 2 or 3 parties.

This system, since beginning is introduced as a temporary, till "political culture" will rise in the country and bonus will not be "necessary" for stability.

p.s.
As far as I know, Armenia does not use this system.

Comment: Please include references to support you answer.